# "Int Cannot be converted to String" While using Method

Tags: java, string, int

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class HWFive {

public static int sumDigits(int number)    
{           
    int sum = 0;
    while(number > 0)
    {
        sum = sum + number % 10;
        number = number / 10;
    }    
    return sum;

}

public static int numLowerCase(String str)
{
    int numLower = 0;
    int index = 0;
    char ch;
    while (index < str.length()){
        ch = str.charAt(index);
        if('a' <= ch && ch <= 'z'){
            numLower++; }
    index++;        
        }
    return numLower;        
}        

public static void main(String[] args){   
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Please enter a number:");
    int number = s.nextInt();
    number = sumDigits(number);
    System.out.println("The sum of all digits is: " + number);

    System.out.print("Please enter a Word: ");
    String str = s.nextLine(); 
    (str) = numLowerCase(str);
    System.out.println("The sum of all digits is: " + str);
}    
}
```

On the 4 last line of that code it keeps telling me "Int Cannot be converted to String" no matter what I do, even using integer.parse, it keeps giving me this error... is it because I'm calling a method at the top?

Comment: Wait - what are you trying to accomplish with `(str) = numLowerCase(str);`?

Comment: Also to potential close voters - this isn't a typo and there's another nuance *besides* the use of the strange syntax.  I'd believe it were a duplicate of the `nextFoo` Scanner question, but there's a bit...more to this one than just that.

Comment: You are trying to resolve the `int` that `numLowerCase()` (Emphasis on the num part) to the `String` `str`. Either resolve the result of the method to a new `int` variable or call it directly in the print statement

Answer (score 2):

**Problem 1**

```
str = numLowerCase(str);
```

You have a method returning an integer value and you're trying to set a string to that integer value, which is not allowed in java although it may seem like an easy conversion.

**Possible Solutions**

1. `str = Integer.toString(numLowerCase(str));`

Converts the integer to a string.

2. `str = String.valueOf(numLowerCase(str));`

Returns the string value of the integer input. (Basically identical to method 1)

3. `str = "" + numLowerCase(str);`

Concatenating an integer to a string is allowed so you can simply add the integer to a blank string.

**Problem 2**

```
System.out.print("Please enter a number:");
int number = s.nextInt();
number = sumDigits(number);
System.out.println("The sum of all digits is: " + number);

System.out.print("Please enter a Word: ");
String str = s.nextLine(); 
(str) = numLowerCase(str);
```

In this block of code, you use scanner::nextInt which makes you enter a number and then hit enter. The  scanner::nextInt only parses the integer that you entered and returns that so there is still a newLine char in the input buffer. When you call your scanner a second time for the scanner::nextLine, it uses that newLine char that's already in the buffer and doesn't allow you to enter new inputs. To fix this, you need to add a line with `scanner.next();` after your scanner.nextInt() so it lets you enter a second input and basically throw away the newLine char.

Answer (score 0):

First,if you want to read input from the console,you can use Scanner's nextLine method,and you should not use the nextLine in combination with the nextInt. The correct is this

```
    public static int sumDigits(int number)
{
    int sum = 0;
    while(number > 0)
    {
        sum = sum + number % 10;
        number = number / 10;
    }
    return sum;

}
public static int numLowerCase(String str)
{
    int numLower = 0;
    int index = 0;
    char ch;
    while (index < str.length()){
        ch = str.charAt(index);
        if('a' <= ch && ch <= 'z'){
            numLower++; }
        index++;
    }
    return numLower;
}


public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Please enter a number:");
    int number = Integer.valueOf( s.nextLine());
    number = sumDigits(number);
    System.out.println("The sum of all digits is: " + number);

    System.out.print("Please enter a Word: ");
    String str = s.nextLine();
    (str) = String.valueOf(numLowerCase(str));
    System.out.println("The sum of all digits is: " + str);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The return type of method numLowerCase() is int. You cannot assign int values to a String type object.
`(str) = numLowerCase(str) + "";`

Should do the trick.

Comment: Wow, no.  This solves the symptom yet introduces two new problems.

Comment: @dave:  When you're ready to have your question answered, some of us will still be around.

Comment: ah yes, it fixed the error, but now I can't use scanner twice. Once I type in one value in the 1st scanner. the 2nd scanner just prints and does not let me type a value in. 

"Please enter a number:67
The sum of all digits is: 13
Please enter a Word: The sum of all digits is: 0"